# Apache .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: apache

Trying to get an older site to redirect to a new one after merge.

blog.example.com to -> store.example.com/blog

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) https://store.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /blog [L]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One RewriteRule should suffice:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://store.example.com/blog/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Then you must have broke it copying? Here's online tester you can try: http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Comment: Thanks that me helped me out alot, got it working with your original code